# preventing nicEdit from creating foreign tags

Tags: php, mysql, forms, nicedit

Am using nicEdit to post content into my database. But I found out that when I post the content, it creates a bunch of tags such as div, p, tags per every paragraph created. This is causing my website to distort when I load the content onto the site.

Why is nicEdit creating all these unwanted div, p tags and is there anyway I can prevent that from happening???

EG.

When I input data eg. ***"This is a very good website"*** nicEdit adds tags like `<div><p>`This is a very good website`</p></div>` to the text! Which shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You're using nicEdit for all the wrong reasons if the end result isn't supposed to be HTML.

Comment: I don't think I understand your answer. What am saying is, when I input data eg "This is a very good website" nicEdit adds tags like <div><p>This is a very good website</p></div> to the text! Which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: I understand; is it possible to use a different WYSIWYG editor? NicEdit doesn't seem to have the ability to change how lines are wrapped. CKEDITOR has a ton of options and can be modified heavily.